# Convert Expression<T, string>> to Expression<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

so I want to make filtering work automaticly based on some easy settings. The code I have is this:

```
public ActionResult Index() // here I want to add filtering for Status I only want to show the active ones
{
    IQueryable<Ticket> cases = db.Cases().AsQueryable();
    cases = cases.EnablePaging().EnableFilterFor(x => x.Status);
    return View(cases);
}
```

EnableFilterFor looks like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> EnableFilterFor<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, string>> keySelector)
{ 
    string filterValue= "Active";
    //Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereexpresion = keySelector.Compile() == "Active"

    queryable = queryable.Where(
       //here do the magic !! so that the result will be 'x=>x.Status == filterValue');
    );
    return queryable;
}
```

I googled a lot, tried many different things but no success. I somehow have to combine the keySelector and the filterValue to work (I need an Expression for the Where method to work). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After testing both solutions (thank you both!) I found out that Poke had the best one. Poke his code is the only code that doesn't change the way that the SQL is generated. When I took a look at Servy his generated SQL it always did an EXTRA Sql select query and an EXTRA and in the WHERE clause... No idea why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IQueryable.Where` requires an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, so that will be the thing we need to build. As we want to integrate something from another expression (a `Expression<Func<T, string>>`), we have to build the expression “by hand”.

So in the end, we want to call `LambdaExpression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(…)` to get our expression for `Where`, but we need to fill in the expression body:

```
// first, we reuse the parameter from the `keySelector` expression
ParameterExpression param = keySelector.Parameters[0];

// The body is now just an equality comparison of the `keySelector`
// body, and the constant `filterValue`
Expression body = Expression.Equal(keySelector.Body, Expression.Constant(filterValue));

// now we just need to create a lambda expression for that body with the
// saved parameter and it’s all done:
queryable = queryable.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param));
```

Comment: -1 because sure you *can* use a `Func`, in the sense that noone is stopping you. But if that were the idea, the parameter and return would not be `IQueryable`.

Comment: @Maximc You realize that this results in the entire database table being pulled down and into memory, instead of having the database filter the items, right?

Comment: Updated my answer, wasn’t aware of the different overload of `IQueryable`. Thanks @Jon.

Comment: @poke It's *not* a different overload of the `Where` on `IQueryable`.  `IQueryable` extends `IEnumerable`.  This is using the `IEnumerable` overload of `Where`, not the `IQueryable` overload, meaning this is all done in LINQ to objects.

Comment: @Servy My original answer was using [`IExpression.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534803.aspx), while [`IQueryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) was desired, which my answer is now using. So yes, it is a different “overload”.

Comment: @poke: You haven't really changed anything. That call to `Lambda` at the end gets you back to square one because it produces compiled code that cannot be communicated to the database. Also, all of those static methods are defined in class `Expression`, not the derived `LambdaExpression`.

Comment: @Jon `Expression.Lambda<T>` returns an `Expression<T>`, so no, this is actually creating an expression, which is then used for `IQueryable.Where`.

Comment: Oke I didn't know that it would pull the whole database, thanks for the info ! And thx for the fixed code.

Comment: @poke It's `IEnumerable`, not `IExpression`.  As I said in my comment, your original revision was using `IEnumerable.Where`.  That is *not* a different overload of `IQueryable.Where`.  The two different methods accept different arguments, and are defined in different types, and so are not overloads of each other.

Comment: @Servy It is a different “overload” in the sense that it uses a different extension method with the same name. I do know the difference, so no need to nitpick there. I do realize that my original revision was wrong because I didn’t know about `IQueryable.Where`; and I fixed it since…

Answer (score 2):

What we'll need here is a `Compose` method, for expressions.  It'll take an expression that uses a value, and another expression that conceptually will use the result of the first expression as its input, generating a new output.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

It will require the ability to replace one expression with another, which we can do using the following:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}

internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Now we can write:

```
public static IQueryable<T> EnableFilterFor<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> queryable, 
    Expression<Func<T, string>> keySelector)
{ 
    string filterValue= "Active";

    return queryable.Where(keySelector.Compose(status => status == filterValue));
}
```

Comment: Poke answer is shorter but it seems to work, is somehow your answer better ? Thx for helping btw

Comment: @Maximc The few methods at the top solve this problem in the general case, rather than just this one case.  It means that every time you ever have this problem in the future you can just call `Compose` and be done with it, rather than requiring explicit expression manipulation every time, which comes with some noticeable margins for error.